# Xamarin Async Constructor

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

For my application I need to fetch some data asynchronously and do some initialization for each page. Unfortunately, a constructor does not allow me to make asynchronous calls. I followed [this article](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/91811/#Comment_91811) and put all of my code into the `OnAppearing` method. However, since then I ran into multiple issues since each platform handles the event a little bit differently. For example, I have pages where you can take pictures, on iOS the `OnAppearing` is called again every time after the camera is closed while Android doesn't. It doesn't seem like a reliable method for my needs, which is also described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical):

> Calls to the `OnDisappearing` and `OnAppearing` overrides cannot be treated as guaranteed indications of page navigation. For example, on iOS, the `OnDisappearing` override is called on the active page when the application terminates.

I am searching for a method/way where I can perform my own initialization. The constructor would be perfect for that but I cannot perform anything asynchronously in there. Please do not provide me with any work arounds, I am searching for a solution that is the "recommended" way or maybe someone with a lot of experience can tell me what they are doing. (I also don't want to .Wait() or .Result as it will lock my app)

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stephen Cleary's excellent [NotifyTaskCompletion](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/NotifyTaskCompletion) class.

You can read more how it works and what to do/don't in these cases in Microsoft's excellent [Async Programming : Patterns for Asynchronous MVVM Applications: Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/march/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-data-binding#a-better-approach). The highlights of this topics are:

> Let’s walk through the core method
>   NotifyTaskCompletion.WatchTaskAsync. This method takes a task
>   representing the asynchronous operation, and (asynchronously) waits
>   for it to complete. Note that the await does not use
>   ConfigureAwait(false); I want to return to the UI context before
>   raising the PropertyChanged notifications. This method violates a
>   common coding guideline here: It has an empty general catch clause. In
>   this case, though, that’s exactly what I want. I don’t want to
>   propagate exceptions directly back to the main UI loop; I want to
>   capture any exceptions and set properties so that the error handling
>   is done via data binding. When the task completes, the type raises
>   PropertyChanged notifications for all the appropriate properties.

A sample usage of it:

```cs
public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
      UrlByteCount = new NotifyTaskCompletion<int>(
        MyStaticService.CountBytesInUrlAsync("http://www.example.com"));
    }
    public NotifyTaskCompletion<int> UrlByteCount { get; private set; }
}
```

Here, the demo is about binding the returned asynchronous value to some bindable property, but of course you can you is without any return value (for simple data loading).

Answer (score -1):

This may be too simple to say, but you CAN run asynchronous tasks in the constructor. Just wrap it in an anonymous Task.

```
public MyConstructor() {
    Task.Run(async () => {
        <Your code>
    }
}
```

Be careful when doing this though as you can get into resource conflict issues if you accidentally open the page twice.

Another thing I like to do is use an _isInit flag, which indicates a first time use, and then never again.